# Cursor ..Ques column Data as Column names and related answer data under resp. Ques Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table which looks like

```
AccNo   Person  Ques    Anwers
1       XXX     Q1      A1
1       XXX     Q2      A2
1       XXX     Q3      A3
1       XXX     Q4      A4
```

I need to write a code so that my output looks like this..

```
AccNo      Person    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
1          XXX       Ans1  Ans2  Ans3  Ans4
```

I have written a cursor but my output looks likes the below

```
AccNo       Person    Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
1           XXX       Ans1          
1           XXX             Ans2        
1           XXX                   Ans3  
1           XXX                         Ans4
```

Please let me know what should I do to get the data into 1 row(1 row for each AccNo) instead of 4 rows.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a cursor, you can use `PIVOT`. If you know the number of rows to transform you can hard-code it via a static pivot:

```
select *
from 
(
    select accNo, person, ques, anwers
    from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
    min(anwers)
    for ques in([Q1], [Q2], [Q3], [Q4])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b01ab/1)

If you don't know the number of columns to transform, then you can use a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ques) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT accno, person,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select accNo, person, ques, anwers
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(anwers)
                for ques in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b01ab/5)

Or you can use an aggregate with a `CASE`:

```
select accno, person,
  max(case when ques = 'Q1' then anwers end) Q1,
  max(case when ques = 'Q2' then anwers end) Q2,
  max(case when ques = 'Q3' then anwers end) Q3,
  max(case when ques = 'Q4' then anwers end) Q4
from yourtable
group by accno, person
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b01ab/3)